# Google script - In the following code, instead of 'includes', how to do 'not includes'

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets, data-extraction

[Sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Pl6Rd9rp9TdxTd_zvXMBqjmv3rgmuM2EFdPv9jGIWD0/edit#gid=0)

This is the code I have now, and what I want to do is also bring in all data from C where text does not include '250p' in col A.

```
const sS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
function grabData() {
  const sheetIn = sS.getSheetByName('data')
  const sheetOut = sS.getSheetByName('Desired Outcome')
  const range = 'A2:B'
  /* Grab all the data from columns A and B and filter it */
  const values = sheetIn.getRange(range).getValues().filter(n => n[0])
  /* Retrieve only the names if it containes 250p */
  /* In format [[a], [b], ...] */
  const parsedValues = values.map((arr) => {
    const [type, name] = arr
    if (type.toLowerCase().includes('250p')) {
      return name.split('\n')
    }
  })
    .filter(n => n)
    .flat()
    .map(n => [n])
  /* Add the values to the Desired Outcome Sheet */
  sheetOut
    .getRange(sheetOut.getLastRow() + 1, 1, parsedValues.length)
    .setValues(parsedValues)
}
```

I tried doing:
`if (!type.toLowerCase().includes('250p')) {`
`if (type.whenTextDoesNotContain('250p')) {`

But on both occasions I get that, that is not a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- Your Spreadsheet has the values in the columns "A" and "C".
- You want to check the column "A". When the value of column "A" doesn't include the text of `250p`, you want to copy the values from the column "C" to the column "A" of the destination sheet. In this case, you want to split the values by `\n`.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, in order to retrieve the values from the columns "A" and "C", I thought that `const range = 'A2:B'` should be `const range = 'A2:C' + sheetIn.getLastRow();`, and also `const [type, name] = arr` is `const [type, , name] = arr`.
- In order to retrieve the rows that `250p` is not included in the column "A", I modified your if statement to `if (!type.toLowerCase().includes('250p')) {`.

When these points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
const sS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
function grabData() {
  const sheetIn = sS.getSheetByName('data');
  const sheetOut = sS.getSheetByName('Desired Outcome');
  const range = 'A2:C' + sheetIn.getLastRow();
  const values = sheetIn.getRange(range).getValues();
  const parsedValues = values.map((arr) => {
    const [type, , name] = arr;
    if (!type.toLowerCase().includes('250p')) {
      return name.split('\n');
    }
  })
    .filter(n => n)
    .flat()
    .map(n => [n]);
  sheetOut
    .getRange(sheetOut.getLastRow() + 1, 1, parsedValues.length)
    .setValues(parsedValues);
}
```

- If you want to retrieve the rows that `250p` is included in the column "A", please modify `if (!type.toLowerCase().includes('250p')) {` to `if (type.toLowerCase().includes('250p')) {`.

#### Note:

- In this modified script, your provided Spreadsheet is used. So, when you change the Spreadsheet, this modified script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

Comment: Thank you so much Tanaike. And also for your detailed explanation. And so '!' means the opposite of a statement?

Comment: @Genny Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `And so '!' means the opposite of a statement?`, that is the logical NOT operator. About this, I thought that you can see the detailed information at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT

Comment: Thank you for the link. No amount of google searching directed me to the reference link :)